# Optimization in R - Efficient Computation of Objective and Gradient

Tags: r, optimization

I need to optimize a set of variables with respect to an objective function. I have the analytical gradient of the function, and would like to use it in the optimization routine. The objective and gradient have some common computations, and I would like to define the functions in the most efficient way possible. The below example demonstrates the issue.

Let `f_obj`, `f_grad` and `f_common` be functions for the objective, gradient and common computations, respectively. The optimization is over the vector `x`. The below code finds a root of the polynomial `y^3 - 3*y^2 + 6*y + 1`, where `y` is a function of `c(x[1], x[2])`. Note that the function `f_common` is called in both `f_obj` and `f_grad`. In my actual problem the common computation is much longer, so I'm looking for a way to define `f_obj` and `f_grad` so that the number of calls to `f_common` is minimized.

```
f_common <- function(x) x[1]^3*x[2]^3 - x[2]

f_obj <- function(x) {
  y <- f_common(x)
  return ( (y^3 - 3*y^2 + 6*y + 1)^2 )
}

f_grad <- function(x) {
  y <- f_common(x)
  return ( 2 * (y^3 - 3*y^2 + 6*y + 1) * (3*y^2 - 6*y + 6)* c(3*x[1]^2*x[2]^3, 3*x[1]^3*x[2]^2 - 1) )
}

optim(par = c(100,100), fn = f_obj, gr = f_grad, method = "BFGS")
```

**UPDATE**

I find that the package `nloptr` offers the facility to input the objective function and its gradient as a list. Is there a way to define other optimizers, (`optim`, `optimx`, `nlminb`, etc.) in a similar manner?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you want>?  The code works.  If you want to minimize the call of f_common, you should not call it and instead hard code y within function.

Comment: Hardcoding the common computations in both functions would be the equivalent of calling f_common (in terms of execution time). I'm looking for a way to eliminate redundant computations. With my code, if the optimization routine is to compute`f_obj` at a point `x` and find its gradient at that point, it would need to call `f_common` twice, but we only need to compute `y` once.

Comment: Maybe you could use a package like [memoise](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/memoise/index.html) to cache the results of `f_common`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Store the value of the common function in global variable to make it available to subsequent function call, as in following:

```
f_common <- function(x) x[1]^3*x[2]^3 - x[2]

f_obj <- function(x) {
  y <<- f_common(x)   # <<- operator stores in parent scope
  return ( (y^3 - 3*y^2 + 6*y + 1)^2 )
}

f_grad <- function(x) {
  return ( 2 * (y^3 - 3*y^2 + 6*y + 1) * (3*y^2 - 6*y + 6)* c(3*x[1]^2*x[2]^3, 3*x[1]^3*x[2]^2 - 1) )
}

y<<-0

optim(par = c(100,100), fn = f_obj, gr = f_grad, method = "BFGS")
```

A couple of notes are worth adding about this solution.

1) Firstly, using the <<- operator, does not strictly speaking assign to a global variable, but rather to one in the parent scope of the function (i.e. the scope from which it was called). Typically this is often global scope. This works fine here and is the better approach.  It is also possible to explicitly use global scope using the assign() function, but there is no need for that here.

2) It should also be noted that it is normally not recommended to use global variables, because they can have unexpected side effects if the same variable name is used elsewhere.  To avoid any possible side effects, I would suggest using a variable name such as global.f_common that will never be used elsewhere and has no danger of side effects. I simply used the name y in the example to be consistent with the nomenclature in the original question. This is one of the rare occasions where giving a variable scope outside of its function may be justified because it is difficult to achieve the desired behaviour another way. Just make sure you use caution and use a unique name (such as global.f_common) as suggested above.

Comment: Are we sure that a call for gradient function with x is always followed by a call for objective function with the same x?  If, say, grad(x2) is computing right after computing obj(x1), then it would cause a problem.  Looks risky unless one understands all procedure within `optim` function.

Comment: I did make several checks on this: using print(y) within the obj and grad functions and using trace option in Optim. The upshot is that this approach follows exacly the same optimisation pathway as calculating y twice as in OP. Also, it's important to realise that it  only matters that optim does not calculate gradient except at location where it has already calculated the objective function, which is the case.

Comment: To avoid the global variable, one could make an environment and store it inside?